# Random Number from Histogram

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, montecarlo

Suppose I create a histogram using scipy/numpy, so I have two arrays: one for the bin counts, and one for the bin edges. If I use the histogram to represent a probability distribution function, how can I efficiently generate random numbers from that distribution?

Comment: Can you clarify this some? Do you want a certain number of random numbers per histogram interval or do you want random numbers based off a weight function that is based off a polynomial interpolation of the histogram values?

Comment: Returning the bin center is fine. Interpolation or fitting isn't necessary.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It's probably what `np.random.choice` does in @Ophion's answer, but you can construct a normalized cumulative density function, then choose based on a uniform random number:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.normal(size=1000)
hist, bins = np.histogram(data, bins=50)

bin_midpoints = bins[:-1] + np.diff(bins)/2
cdf = np.cumsum(hist)
cdf = cdf / cdf[-1]
values = np.random.rand(10000)
value_bins = np.searchsorted(cdf, values)
random_from_cdf = bin_midpoints[value_bins]

plt.subplot(121)
plt.hist(data, 50)
plt.subplot(122)
plt.hist(random_from_cdf, 50)
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

A 2D case can be done as follows:

```
data = np.column_stack((np.random.normal(scale=10, size=1000),
                        np.random.normal(scale=20, size=1000)))
x, y = data.T                        
hist, x_bins, y_bins = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=(50, 50))
x_bin_midpoints = x_bins[:-1] + np.diff(x_bins)/2
y_bin_midpoints = y_bins[:-1] + np.diff(y_bins)/2
cdf = np.cumsum(hist.ravel())
cdf = cdf / cdf[-1]

values = np.random.rand(10000)
value_bins = np.searchsorted(cdf, values)
x_idx, y_idx = np.unravel_index(value_bins,
                                (len(x_bin_midpoints),
                                 len(y_bin_midpoints)))
random_from_cdf = np.column_stack((x_bin_midpoints[x_idx],
                                   y_bin_midpoints[y_idx]))
new_x, new_y = random_from_cdf.T

plt.subplot(121, aspect='equal')
plt.hist2d(x, y, bins=(50, 50))
plt.subplot(122, aspect='equal')
plt.hist2d(new_x, new_y, bins=(50, 50))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this will certainly work! Can it be generalized to higher dimensional histograms?

Comment: @xvtk I've edited my answer with a 2D histogram. You should be able to apply the same scheme for higher dimensional distributions.

Comment: If you are using python 2, you need to add the "from __future__ import division" import, or change the cdf normalization line to 
cdf = cdf / float(cdf[-1])

Comment: You are absolutely right, Noam. It has become so second nature to me to have that be the first line of every Python I write, that i keep forgetting it isn't standard behavior. Have edited my answer.

Comment: I've also added to your code (as a new answer) an example how to generate random numbers from the kde (kernel density estimation) of the histogram, which captures better the "generator mechanism" of the histogram.

Answer (score 27):

@Jaime solution is great, but you should consider using the kde (kernel density estimation) of the histogram. A great explanation why it's problematic to do statistics over histogram, and why you should use kde instead can be found [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/url/mglerner.com/HistogramsVsKDE.ipynb)

I edited @Jaime's code to show how to use kde from scipy. It looks almost the same, but captures better the histogram generator.

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde

def run():
    data = np.random.normal(size=1000)
    hist, bins = np.histogram(data, bins=50)

    x_grid = np.linspace(min(data), max(data), 1000)
    kdepdf = kde(data, x_grid, bandwidth=0.1)
    random_from_kde = generate_rand_from_pdf(kdepdf, x_grid)

    bin_midpoints = bins[:-1] + np.diff(bins) / 2
    random_from_cdf = generate_rand_from_pdf(hist, bin_midpoints)

    plt.subplot(121)
    plt.hist(data, 50, normed=True, alpha=0.5, label='hist')
    plt.plot(x_grid, kdepdf, color='r', alpha=0.5, lw=3, label='kde')
    plt.legend()
    plt.subplot(122)
    plt.hist(random_from_cdf, 50, alpha=0.5, label='from hist')
    plt.hist(random_from_kde, 50, alpha=0.5, label='from kde')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()


def kde(x, x_grid, bandwidth=0.2, **kwargs):
    """Kernel Density Estimation with Scipy"""
    kde = gaussian_kde(x, bw_method=bandwidth / x.std(ddof=1), **kwargs)
    return kde.evaluate(x_grid)


def generate_rand_from_pdf(pdf, x_grid):
    cdf = np.cumsum(pdf)
    cdf = cdf / cdf[-1]
    values = np.random.rand(1000)
    value_bins = np.searchsorted(cdf, values)
    random_from_cdf = x_grid[value_bins]
    return random_from_cdf
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you doing `bw_method=bandwidth / x.std(ddof=1)` ? I would think `bw_method=bandwidth * x.std(ddof=1)` instead?

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps something like this. Uses the count of the histogram as a weight and chooses values of indices based on this weight.

```
import numpy as np

initial=np.random.rand(1000)
values,indices=np.histogram(initial,bins=20)
values=values.astype(np.float32)
weights=values/np.sum(values)

#Below, 5 is the dimension of the returned array.
new_random=np.random.choice(indices[1:],5,p=weights)
print new_random

#[ 0.55141614  0.30226256  0.25243184  0.90023117  0.55141614]
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem as the OP and I would like to share my approach to this problem.

Following [Jaime answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17822210/2029132) and  [Noam Peled answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29488780/2029132) I've built a solution for a 2D problem using a [Kernel Density Estimation (KDE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation).

Frist, let's generate some random data and then calculate its [Probability Density Function (PDF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) from the KDE. I will use the [example available in SciPy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html) for that.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

def measure(n):
    "Measurement model, return two coupled measurements."
    m1 = np.random.normal(size=n)
    m2 = np.random.normal(scale=0.5, size=n)
    return m1+m2, m1-m2

m1, m2 = measure(2000)
xmin = m1.min()
xmax = m1.max()
ymin = m2.min()
ymax = m2.max()

X, Y = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:100j, ymin:ymax:100j]
positions = np.vstack([X.ravel(), Y.ravel()])
values = np.vstack([m1, m2])
kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(values)
Z = np.reshape(kernel(positions).T, X.shape)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(np.rot90(Z), cmap=plt.cm.gist_earth_r,
          extent=[xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
ax.plot(m1, m2, 'k.', markersize=2)
ax.set_xlim([xmin, xmax])
ax.set_ylim([ymin, ymax])
```

And the plot is:

[image: KDE and Scatter plot of the "original" data.]

Now, we obtain random data  from the PDF obtained from the KDE, which is the variable `Z`.

```
# Generate the bins for each axis
x_bins = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, Z.shape[0]+1)
y_bins = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, Z.shape[1]+1)

# Find the middle point for each bin
x_bin_midpoints = x_bins[:-1] + np.diff(x_bins)/2
y_bin_midpoints = y_bins[:-1] + np.diff(y_bins)/2

# Calculate the Cumulative Distribution Function(CDF)from the PDF
cdf = np.cumsum(Z.ravel())
cdf = cdf / cdf[-1] # Normalização

# Create random data
values = np.random.rand(10000)

# Find the data position
value_bins = np.searchsorted(cdf, values)
x_idx, y_idx = np.unravel_index(value_bins,
                                (len(x_bin_midpoints),
                                 len(y_bin_midpoints)))

# Create the new data
new_data = np.column_stack((x_bin_midpoints[x_idx],
                            y_bin_midpoints[y_idx]))
new_x, new_y = new_data.T
```

And we can calculate the KDE from this new data and the plot it.

```
kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(new_data.T)
new_Z = np.reshape(kernel(positions).T, X.shape)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(np.rot90(new_Z), cmap=plt.cm.gist_earth_r,
          extent=[xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
ax.plot(new_x, new_y, 'k.', markersize=2)
ax.set_xlim([xmin, xmax])
ax.set_ylim([ymin, ymax])
```

[image: KDe and scatter plot from the new data]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution, that returns datapoints that are uniformly distributed  within each bin instead of the bin center:

```
def draw_from_hist(hist, bins, nsamples = 100000):
    cumsum = [0] + list(I.np.cumsum(hist))
    rand = I.np.random.rand(nsamples)*max(cumsum)
    return [I.np.interp(x, cumsum, bins) for x in rand]
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things do not work well for the solutions suggested by @daniel, @arco-bast, *et al*

Taking the last example

```
def draw_from_hist(hist, bins, nsamples = 100000):
    cumsum = [0] + list(I.np.cumsum(hist))
    rand = I.np.random.rand(nsamples)*max(cumsum)
    return [I.np.interp(x, cumsum, bins) for x in rand]
```

This assumes that at least the first bin has zero content, which may or may not be true.  Secondly, this assumes that the value of the PDF is at the *upper* bound of the bins, which it isn't - it's mostly in the centre of the bin.

Here's another solution done in two parts

```
def init_cdf(hist,bins):
    """Initialize CDF from histogram

    Parameters
    ----------
        hist : array-like, float of size N
            Histogram height 
        bins : array-like, float of size N+1
            Histogram bin boundaries 

    Returns:
    --------
        cdf : array-like, float of size N+1
    """
    from numpy import concatenate, diff,cumsum

    # Calculate half bin sizes
    steps  = diff(bins) / 2  # Half bin size

    # Calculate slope between bin centres 
    slopes = diff(hist) / (steps[:-1]+steps[1:]) 

    # Find height of end points by linear interpolation
    # - First part is linear interpolation from second over first
    #   point to lowest bin edge
    # - Second part is linear interpolation left neighbor to 
    #   right neighbor up to but not including last point
    # - Third part is linear interpolation from second to last point 
    #   over last point to highest bin edge
    # Can probably be done more elegant
    ends = concatenate(([hist[0] - steps[0] * slopes[0]], 
                        hist[:-1] + steps[:-1] * slopes,
                        [hist[-1] + steps[-1] * slopes[-1]]))

    # Calculate cumulative sum 
    sum = cumsum(ends)
    # Subtract off lower bound and scale by upper bound 
    sum -= sum[0]
    sum /= sum[-1]

    # Return the CDF 
    return sum

def sample_cdf(cdf,bins,size):
    """Sample a CDF defined at specific points.

    Linear interpolation between defined points 

    Parameters
    ----------
       cdf : array-like, float, size N
           CDF evaluated at all points of bins. First and 
           last point of bins are assumed to define the domain
           over which the CDF is normalized. 
       bins : array-like, float, size N
           Points where the CDF is evaluated.  First and last points 
           are assumed to define the end-points of the CDF's domain
       size : integer, non-zero
           Number of samples to draw 
    Returns
    -------
        sample : array-like, float, of size ``size``
             Random sample
    """
    from numpy import interp
    from numpy.random import random 

    return interp(random(size), cdf, bins)

# Begin example code
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# initial histogram, coarse binning
hist,bins = np.histogram(np.random.normal(size=1000),np.linspace(-2,2,21))

# Calculate CDF, make sample, and new histogram w/finer binning
cdf = init_cdf(hist,bins)
sample = sample_cdf(cdf,bins,1000)
hist2,bins2 = np.histogram(sample,np.linspace(-3,3,61))

# Calculate bin centres and widths 
mx = (bins[1:]+bins[:-1])/2
dx = np.diff(bins)
mx2 = (bins2[1:]+bins2[:-1])/2
dx2 = np.diff(bins2)

# Plot, taking care to show uncertainties and so on
plt.errorbar(mx,hist/dx,np.sqrt(hist)/dx,dx/2,'.',label='original')
plt.errorbar(mx2,hist2/dx2,np.sqrt(hist2)/dx2,dx2/2,'.',label='new')
plt.legend()
```

Sorry, I don't know how to get this to show up in StackOverflow, so copy'n'paste and run to see the point.

Comment: My solution does not assume that the first bin is empty. Try `draw_from_hist([1],[0,1])`. This draws uniformly from the interval [0,1], as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this question when I was looking for a way to generate a random array based on a distribution of another array. If this would be in numpy, I would call it `random_like()` function.

Then I realized, I have written a package [Redistributor](https://gitlab.com/paloha/redistributor/-/blob/master/redistributor/redistributor.py) which might do this for me even though the package was created with a bit different motivation (Sklearn transformer capable of transforming data from an arbitrary distribution to an arbitrary known distribution for machine learning purposes). Of course I understand unnecessary dependencies are not desired, but at least knowing this package might be useful to you someday. The thing OP asked about is basically done under the hood here.

WARNING: under the hood, everything is done in 1D. The package also implements multidimensional wrapper, but I have not written this example using it as I find it to be too niche.

**Installation:**

`pip install git+https://gitlab.com/paloha/redistributor`

**Implementation:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def random_like(source, bins=0, seed=None):
    from redistributor import Redistributor
    np.random.seed(seed)
    noise = np.random.uniform(source.min(), source.max(), size=source.shape)
    s = Redistributor(bins=bins, bbox=[source.min(), source.max()]).fit(source.ravel())
    s.cdf, s.ppf = s.source_cdf, s.source_ppf
    r = Redistributor(target=s, bbox=[noise.min(), noise.max()]).fit(noise.ravel())
    return r.transform(noise.ravel()).reshape(noise.shape)

source = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=(100,100))
t = random_like(source, bins=80) # More bins more precision (0 = automatic)

# Plotting
plt.figure(figsize=(12,4))
plt.subplot(121); plt.title(f'Distribution of source data, shape: {source.shape}')
plt.hist(source.ravel(), bins=100)
plt.subplot(122); plt.title(f'Distribution of generated data, shape: {t.shape}') 
plt.hist(t.ravel(), bins=100); plt.show()
```

[image: Comparing histograms of source and generated arrays]

**Explanation:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from redistributor import Redistributor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

# We have some source array with "some unknown" distribution (e.g. an image)
# For the sake of example we just generate a random gaussian matrix
source = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=(100,100))
plt.figure(figsize=(12,4))
plt.subplot(121); plt.title('Source data'); plt.imshow(source, origin='lower') 
plt.subplot(122); plt.title('Source data hist'); plt.hist(source.ravel(), bins=100); plt.show()

# We want to generate a random matrix from the distribution of the source
# So we create a random uniformly distributed array called noise
noise = np.random.uniform(source.min(), source.max(), size=(100,100))
plt.figure(figsize=(12,4))
plt.subplot(121); plt.title('Uniform noise'); plt.imshow(noise, origin='lower')
plt.subplot(122); plt.title('Uniform noise hist'); plt.hist(noise.ravel(), bins=100); plt.show()

# Then we fit (approximate) the source distribution using Redistributor
# This step internally approximates the cdf and ppf functions.
s = Redistributor(bins=200, bbox=[source.min(), source.max()]).fit(source.ravel())

# A little naming workaround to make obj s work as a target distribution
s.cdf = s.source_cdf
s.ppf = s.source_ppf

# Here we create another Redistributor but now we use the fitted Redistributor s as a target
r = Redistributor(target=s, bbox=[noise.min(), noise.max()])

# Here we fit the Redistributor r to the noise array's distribution
r.fit(noise.ravel())

# And finally, we transform the noise into the source's distribution
t = r.transform(noise.ravel()).reshape(noise.shape)
plt.figure(figsize=(12,4))
plt.subplot(121); plt.title('Transformed noise'); plt.imshow(t, origin='lower')
plt.subplot(122); plt.title('Transformed noise hist'); plt.hist(t.ravel(), bins=100); plt.show()

# Computing the difference between the two arrays
print('Mean Squared Error between source and transformed: ', mean_squared_error(source, t))
```

[image]

Mean Squared Error between source and transformed:  2.0574123162302143